# Can't seem to get nginx to use cookies when loading site as a proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy

Trying to get nginx to use cookies when using proxy_pass, but all of the configurations I've tried so far don't seem to pass them.  Pretty much at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong.

```
    location / {

        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_pass https://example.com/;

        proxy_set_header                Host example.com;
        proxy_set_header                X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header                Cookie $http_cookie;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

        proxy_cookie_domain proxy.net example.com;

    }
```

Is the most recent block I've tried, but still no go